# Iterate through list return by find command in shell script

Tags: shell-script

I am trying to find `.csv` file in directory and assign its name to a variable in a shell script.

I have written following code.

```
x="$(find extracted_data/*.csv)"
echo "$x"
IFS = $'\n'
for i in "${x[@]}"; do
        echo "${i}"
done
```

However, after running this code I get following output:

```
extracted_data/another_file.csv 
extracted_data/sample.csv 
sheet.sh: 4: IFS: not found 
sheet.sh: 5: Bad substitution
```

What is wrong done in code as it is giving those two errors?

I have followed following two links for my code
[loop through file names returned by find](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9612090/how-to-loop-through-file-names-returned-by-find) and [for array](https://www.linuxjournal.com/content/bash-arrays)

Comment: Please consider adding a tag to indicate which shell you are using, it will help identify errors that are more subtle due to shell-specific syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To start off, I will reiterate the recommendation to [not loop over `find`'s output](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/321697/377345).

Now, to address your question: There is a rather simple syntax error in your script. The variable assignment

```
IFS = $'\n'
```

*must not* have spaces around the `=` sign. Shell variable assignments must be of the form

```
IFS=$'\n'
```

You may want to check out [`shellcheck`](https://shellcheck.net), also available as standalone tool in many Linux distributions, to guard against such errors.

**That said**, what you want to accomplish can be done in a simpler and less error-prone way by simply stating

```
for x in extracted_data/*.csv
do
  echo "$x"
done
```

This wouldn't even break if the filenames contained newlines (which unfortunately is a valid character for filenames).